# jquery $.post return type assignment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jquery to submit an ajax request using post to my php code. I would like to use the returned data type to assign it to a javascript variable.
How can I do that?

when I do var updatedNumOfPosts = parseInt( data ); it says that updatedNumOfPosts is undefined. I have also tried var updatedNumOfPosts = data, etc. Below is my code, help is much appreciated.

javascript function

```
 function pagerefresh()
{

$.post("searchPresentation.php", {get_num_posts:"yes"}, function ( data ){


    var udpatedNumOfPosts = parseInt(data); //I would like to assign this variable
   }
}
```

php function

```
if (isset($_POST['get_num_posts']))
{ 
$user = $_POST['user'];
$num =  num_of_posts($user);
echo $num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$user = $_POST['user'];`
Are u passing any 'user' variable?

Well, you should declare variable before the function in order to use in everywehere.

like this:

```
var udpatedNumOfPosts;

function pagerefresh() {
    $.post("searchPresentation.php", {get_num_posts:"yes", user: "somedata"}, function ( data ){
        udpatedNumOfPosts = parseInt(data);
   }
}
```

or there's a mistake: uPDatedNumOfPosts, not uDPated

**Update**: try also to convert object into string:

```
function objToString (obj) {
  var str = '';
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        str += p + '::' + obj[p] + '\n';
    }
  }
  return str;
}

udpatedNumOfPosts=objToString(data)-0;
```

Comment: Specifically, you need to pass a "user" variable in the second parameter of `$.post`.

Comment: I can't figure out what the returned data type is. I fixed all the syntax, though  updatedNumOfPosts = parseInt(data) yields a NaN. I don't know how to convert the value given to an integer

Comment: @user3769015 could you show content of data? `console.log(data)` would be great.

Comment: document.write(data) yields 15. Thus indicating that there are 15 rows in the table

Comment: Don't know what can it be. Try `updatedNumOfPosts=data-0;` instead of `parseInt()`

Comment: Btw, why do u need parseInt()?

Comment: when I did data-0 i got NaN

Comment: I need parseInt so I can convert the data given, which I thought would be returned as a string, and then convert the string to an integer

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try to convert object into string (probably .post returns you an object, not a string)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket of the post function, please change your code to be:

```
function pagerefresh()
{
   $.post("searchPresentation.php", {get_num_posts:"yes"}, function ( data ){
     var udpatedNumOfPosts = parseInt(data); //I would like to assign this variable
   });
}
```

Comment: Please try this and let me know what is the result for it: typeof(data). I need to know the type of data, so that we can determine if it can be used with parseInt or not.